# How to add new columns to a dataframe from existing rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
             CUI      SDUI  SAB  TTY                   STR
325040  C0011405   D003788  MSH   MH  Dental Pulp Diseases
325054  C0011405  10012328  MDR  LLT  Dental pulp disorder
325054  C0011405  10012326  MDR  LLT  Dental pulp disorders
325055  C0011405  10012328  MDR   PT  Dental pulp disorder
```

I would like to use a column (SAB) to generate another columns. The expected output is:

```
        CUI       SDUI_MSH    TTY_MSH  STR_MSH               SDUI_MDR    TTY_MDR  STR_MDR
325040  C0011405  D003788     MH       Dental Pulp Diseases  10012328    LLT      Dental pulp disorder
325040  C0011405  D003788     MH       Dental Pulp Diseases  10012326    LLT      Dental pulp disorders
325055  C0011405  D003788     MH       Dental Pulp Diseases  10012328    PT       Dental pulp disorder
```

I have tried so far is 'pivot_table' function

```py
df_umls = df_umls.pivot_table(index=['CUI'], columns='SAB', values=['SDUI', 'TTY', 'STR']).reset_index()
df_umls.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() for col in df_umls.columns.values]
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: There could be multiple rows per CUI id. The OP is edited for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

With the dataframe you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "CUI": ["C0011405", "C0011405", "C0011405"],
        "SDUI": ["D003788", "10012328", "10012328"],
        "SAB": ["MSH", "MDR", "MDR"],
        "TTY": ["MH", "LLT", "PT"],
        "STR": ["Dental Pulp Diseases", "Dental pulp disorder", "Dental pulp disorder"],
    },
    index=[325040, 3250054, 325055],
)
```

Here is one way to do it with the help of Pandas [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) method:

```py
new_df = pd.concat(
    [
        df.loc[df["SAB"] == "MSH", :]
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .drop(columns="SAB")
        .rename(columns={"SDUI": "SDUI_MSH", "TTY": "TTY_MSH", "STR": "STR_MSH"}),
        df.loc[df["SAB"] == "MDR", :]
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .drop(columns=["SAB", "CUI"])
        .rename(columns={"SDUI": "SDUI_MDR", "TTY": "TTY_MDR", "STR": "STR_MDR"}),
    ],
    axis=1,
).fillna(method="ffill")

new_df.index = [325040, 325055]
```

```py
print(new_df)
# Output
             CUI SDUI_MSH TTY_MSH               STR_MSH  SDUI_MDR TTY_MDR  \
325040  C0011405  D003788      MH  Dental Pulp Diseases  10012328     LLT   
325055  C0011405  D003788      MH  Dental Pulp Diseases  10012328      PT   

                     STR_MDR  
325040  Dental pulp disorder  
325055  Dental pulp disorder
```